# Is a website without authentication vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, csrf

I just started learning about CSRF.
As per [OWASP CSRF Article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF)

`CSRF is an attack which forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which he/she is currently authenticated`

If a website doesn't accept any user authentication or if authentication information is not stored in cookies does that mean that it is not vulnerable to CSRF.

I developed a website which asks user to enter his ticket information, checks info with database, if correct user will be navigated to a page where he needs to provide his credit card information and his record will be updated.  Do I need to worry about CSRF?  Or ticket information itself is considered as authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to worry about cross site request forgery if your site uses sessions that allow users to do privileged actions.  Since I assume that you create a session property indicating that the user's ticket info is valid, yes you do.

Comment: I was able to test my website using CSRF Tester and it was vulnerable to this attack.  So, I need to worry about CSRF. Thanks.